# Having 2 css code blocks in html files how to make only one work using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

So we have 1 html file (required). In there 2 css style blocks and one JS block. how to make it possible to set to use one of the styles from JS? (I need it to work in IE6 IE7 IE8 FF and chrome 9 =) I need to give one css for IE9 and Chrome 8 and up and another CSS for all others.

```
<style type="text/css" >
H1 {font-size: 24pt; font-family: arial}
</style>

<style type="text/css">
H1 {font-size: 15pt;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use conditional comments to target IE6 specifically, like this:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<style type="text/css">
  H1 {font-size: 15pt;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Or the other way around, whichever it is..but whatever's inside these comments will *only* apply to IE6. No JavaScript is required for the above approach :)

Comment: I think he was asking how to do that, in javascript.

Comment: @Konerak - I agree, but sometimes the answer is " *don't* do it in JavaScript, there's a much simpler way".

Comment: Agreed, but we don't know yet why he wants to do it in JS - maybe a user gets two buttons to select the font-size?

Comment: @Konerak - The question specifically mentions IE6, which does had inherent styling issues...so I assume that's the problem :)

Comment: ... ok I see your way... How to make it give me one CSS for IE9 and chrome and another css for all others?

Comment: @Kabumbus I think you accepted an answer that doesn't solve your problem since chrome doesn't support conditional comments.

Comment: @Hemlock - There's no need for other styles here...since CSS3 declarations will just be ignored in earlier browsers.  Using browser detection for styles is *not* a good way to do things, pretty much ever. Use feature detection.

Comment: @Nick Are you reading the posts from the OP? He is still asking for ways to add styles specific to chrome. Tell him there's no need for other styles.

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative way involving JS and handing chrome. (I learned this form ExtJs but I'm not sure where it originated.)

Load a browser detection script. PPK's is pretty good: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html.

Add classes to document.body.

```
document.body.className += ' ' + BrowserDetect.browser 
  + ' ' + BrowserDetect.browser + '-' + BrowserDetect.version;
```

Now write your css like this

```
H1 {
  font-size: 24pt; 
  font-family: arial;
}

.Explorer-6 H1 {
  font-size: 15pt;
}

.Chrome-9 H1 {
  /* ... */
}
```

You could mix the OS in there too, but I'm not sure you'll ever need it.